# The conjugate of a sylow $p$-subgroup is a sylow $p$-subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

Second Sylow theorem states that all Sylow $p$-subgroups are conjugate. But reviewing my proof it seems to me that we also prove that all the conjugates of a Sylow $p$-subgroup are Sylow $p$-subgroups.

I can include the proof if needed but can anybody confirm me this idea? Or give a counterexample?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general if $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ and $g\in G$, then we have $|gHg^{-1}|=|H|$, so it follows that the conjugates of a Sylow subgroup are also Sylow subgroups.

Comment: In general, an image of a Sylow p-subgroup by an automorphism of $G$ is a Sylow p-subgroup.

Comment: And even more generally any property of a subgroup that can be expressed purely in group language will be preserved by conjugation or any other automorphism.

Comment: @hmakholmleftoverMonica what is "group language"?

Comment: As trivial as it is, one need first to prove that $gHg^{-1}$ is a group.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but that is more or less trivial, once you know that conjugation by a fixed element is an automorphism.

If $H$ and $H'$ are conjugate subgroups of $G$, then the inner automorphism of $G$ that takes $H$ to $H'$ will also take any subgroup *between* $H$ and $G$ to an isomorphic subgroup between $H'$ and $G$. Therefore if $H'$ is a maximal $p$-subgroup, and $H$ will also be a maximal $p$-subgroup, and vice versa.

Comment: Is what you are saying the same as the following? Let $H$ and $K$ be subgroups of a group $G$ such that $H\leq K$. Let $\phi_a$ be an inner automorphism of $G$. I.e. $a\in G$ and  $\phi_a(x)=axa^{-1}$, for all $x\in G$. Then the image of $H$ under $\phi_a$ is a subgroup of the image of $K$ under $\phi_a$, that is $\phi_a(H) \leq \phi_a(K)$.