# Prove that if $H$ and $K$ are Sylow $p$-subgroups, then $H=K$.

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, sylow-theory

Let $G$ be a finite abelian group and let p be a positive prime number that divides the
order of $G$. Prove that if H and K are Sylow p-subgroups, then $H = K$.

I'll first assume that $H$ and $K$ are Sylow $p$-subgroups which tells me $H=p^n$ and $K= p^n$...I donʻt even know if that's correct haha. I am trying not to hate group theory, help please (RA > GT). Just need some motivation to set me in right direction. Clearly I know I will use the fact that it is abelian to show $H=K$ at some point haha. :)

Comment: @PhysicsBish By Sylow's theorem, two Sylow $p$-subgroups are conjugate. But then, $G$ is abelian...

Comment: right thanks guys makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $H$ and $K$ are Sylow $p$-subgroups, [they are conjugate by Sylow's Theorems](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1897971/104041). Hence $gHg^{-1}=K$ for $g\in G$; that is, $gH=Kg$. But $G$ is abelian, so $gH=gK$. Cancel $g$ by multiplying by $g^{-1}$ on the left.

Comment: Wow I knew it was simple. It makes sense coupled with other comments. Thanks Shaun. This forced online learning is killing me so you may see quite a few questions on here from me. Stay tuned. haha

Comment: You're welcome, @PhysicsBish :)